# ViewScoped CDI bean recreated after some AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2, view-scope, uirepeat

I have a CDI ViewScoped bean and a JSF page. After a couple of AJAX requests the bean somehow recreated.
Here is the full code of the application:

index.xhtml

```xhtml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        Hello from Facelets
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{questionBean.newTag}"></h:inputText>
            <h:commandButton value="Add Tag">
                <f:ajax listener="#{questionBean.addTag()}" execute="@form" render="@form"></f:ajax>
            </h:commandButton>
            <ui:repeat value="#{questionBean.tagsOfQuestion}" var="tag">
                <h:outputLabel value="#{tag}"></h:outputLabel>
                <h:commandButton value="X">
                    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{questionBean.removeTag(tag)}" render="@form" execute="@form"/>
                </h:commandButton>
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the backing CDI bean
QuestionBean.java

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
    import javax.inject.Named;

    @Named
    @ViewScoped    
    public class QuestionBean {
        private String newTag;
        private List<String> tagsOfQuestion = new ArrayList<String>();
        private Date dateCreated = new Date();

    public QuestionBean(){
        System.out.println("Date Created : "+dateCreated);
    }

    public void addTag(){
        if(!newTag.isEmpty()){
            getTagsOfQuestion().add(newTag);
        }
        newTag = "";
    }

    public void removeTag(String tagToRemove){
        getTagsOfQuestion().remove(tagToRemove);
    }

    public String getNewTag() {
        return newTag;
    }

    public void setNewTag(String newTag) {
        this.newTag = newTag;
    }

    public List<String> getTagsOfQuestion() {
        return tagsOfQuestion;
    }

    public void setTagsOfQuestion(List<String> tagsOfQuestion) {
        this.tagsOfQuestion = tagsOfQuestion;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I had the same problem when I tried it - Netbeans 8 and JSF 2.2.0 too.

Works for me after I updated Glassfish - grab javax.faces.jar from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/) - I took the very newest, 2.2.8-02, and replaced the one in glassfish/glassfish/modules.

Don't know what the error was or exactly when it was fixed though.

Hope it works for you too.