# ViewState lost after AJAX request

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, weblogic12c

I have a very strange error with the following code:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:panelGroup id="myPanelGroup">
     ...
       <h:commandButton
            value="randomtext" 
            action="#{mybean.action}" tabindex="301"        
            <f:ajax execute=":myPanelGroup" render=":messages @form"/>
       </h:commandButton>
       </h:panelGroup>
    ...
</h:form>
```

So the problem is that after I click on the button the form (myForm) looses its viewState after render. The strange is that in my dev env it is working, but on an other server it is not. Have I made some common mistake with this kind of execute/render pair settings or what else could cause such problem? I was also wondering that probably the 2 servers have different Mojarra version or something like that.

The messages in the render attribute is an id of a panelgroup in an other form.

The container is a WebLogic server with JSf 2.1.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It must be mojorra version problem. I had the same problem updating javax.faces.jar to latest version solved my issue. 

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064509/viewscoped-cdi-bean-recreated-after-some-ajax-requests

Comment: Yeah as far as i can see my local uses 1.0.0.0_2-1-5 while the other server uses 1.0.0.0_2-1-20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out it is a common JSF issue that can be solved with the following library:

http://showcase.omnifaces.org/scripts/FixViewState

More info:
http://balusc.blogspot.hu/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm